# Nest.JS - Global authentication guard

Tags: node.js, nestjs, passport.js

I want to implement a global authentication guard in My NestJS application that will simply read certain headers and assign user values based on those headers, for every request that comes in.

I implemented this simple logic and registered my global guard in my main module, however for some reason all my requests fail with '401 Unauthorized'. I tried to place log messages inside `internal.strategy.ts`, however I don't see them getting called.

Any idea why the strategy is not called?

This is my `main.ts`:

```
import { NestFactory, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as logging from './logging';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import config from './config';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from './auth/guards/local-auth.guard';

async function bootstrap(port: string | number) {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalGuards(new LocalAuthGuard())
  await app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0');

  logging.logger.info(`Listening on 0.0.0.0:${port}`);
}

bootstrap(config.port);
```

This is my `auth.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { InternalStrategy } from './stategies/internal.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule],
  providers: [AuthService, InternalStrategy ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

This is my `auth.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Role } from 'src/workspaces/interfaces/models';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    validateUser(headers: Headers): any {
        const workspaceId = headers['workspace-id'];
        const workspaceRole = Role[headers['workspace-role']];

        return {
            workspaceId: workspaceId,
            workspaceRole: workspaceRole
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `internal.strategy.ts`:

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class InternalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'internal') {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({ passReqToCallback: true });
  }

  async validate(req: Request): Promise<any> {
    console.log('Validate internal strategy')
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(req.headers);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    
    return user;
  }
}
```

Here is my `local-auth.guard.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('internal') {}
```

Comment: Can you show what a sample request looks like, and the `LocalAuthGuard`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel `LocalAuthGuard` is simply a wrapper class that extends `AuthGuard('internal')`, because you can't add a new global guard of type `AuthGuard` without it. As for the request - it can be anything as long as it contains the headers to validate.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? @gUnleash

Answer (score 0):

In terms of dependency injection, global guards registered from outside of any module, cannot inject dependencies since this is done outside the context of any module. In order to solve this issue, you can set up a guard directly from any module using the following construction:

Please read nestjs docs.
https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#binding-guards

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: LocalAuthGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```